# Is there a computationally-accessible metric of "reactivity" in the medicinal-chemistry sense?

Tags: xtb, reactivity

Occasionally a med-chemist will remark that they think a particular molecule has a 'reactive centre' and so should be de-prioritised (in the context of hit- and drug- discovery).

Leaving aside known metabolic enzymes, which will catalyse certain reactions, speeding them up beyond what you'd see passively, is there some metric available to highlight 'reactive centres'? Perhaps Fukui indices are suitable here - but, as [noted on the XTB website](https://xtb-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sp.html#fukui-index):

> As the Fukui indexes depend on occupation numbers and population analysis (see Properties), they are sensitive toward basis set changes. Therefore Fukui indexes should not be recognized as absolute numbers but as relative parameters in the same system.

Comment: The note on the xtb website is probably intended in the limited context of xtb itself, which uses a basis set of limited size since the tight-binding method also has inherent error.

Comment: thanks @SusiLehtola - by 'system' do you think they mean molecular system (i.e. don't compare across different molecules) or basis set (i.e. don't compare across different basis sets)?

Comment: I guess Fukui indices are suitable to find out nucleophilic or electrophilic centres. Although reactivity really depends on the enzymes available in the body. Specific enzymes look for specific functional groups so I guess it is hard to have a unified metric. Also, some people have done research on identifying toxicity form structures, and there are some substructures which tend to indicate toxicity at specific point (e.g. mitchondrial toxicity)

Comment: I guess Fukui indices are suitable to find out nucleophilic or electrophilic centres. Although reactivity really depends on the enzymes available in the body. Specific enzymes look for specific functional groups so I guess it is hard to have a unified metric. Also, some people have done research on identifying toxicity form structures, and there are some substructures which tend to indicate toxicity at specific point (e.g. mitchondrial toxicity)

Comment: @lewiso1 it's obvious they mean molecules. Comparisons between basis sets are meaningless in general; the only important thing are values converged to the complete basis set limit! If one did a proper comparison (i.e. employing a quantitatively accurate method at the complete basis set limit) one could actually look deeper into the Fukui functions...

Comment: obvious to you maybe :) it sounds like you know a lot about the topic, if you could submit an answer that would be really helpful!

Comment: lewiso1, I guess your most recent comment was directed at @SusiLehtola but it's possible that Susi didn't see the comment because you didn't use the @ character to ping the username. Also, if you have found the answer over the last 7 months, please feel free to write a self-answer or at least update us!

Comment: thanks for the ping - I still think about this and will update if I come across an answer. Also @SusiLehtola ping :)

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but now that it has been more than 1 year, can you update us please? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question?

Comment: @NikeDattani I could never find an answer unfortuantely. It was never urgent but it would still be useful!

Comment: It doesn't look like it's going to get an answer with the population we currently have. We can re-visit it if someone wants to answer it (they can leave a comment and the question will be opened and bumped to the top of the home page).